# how to embed video youtube for load video only first time and play loop in offline

Tags: youtube

i want to show youtube video in my website,
and set embed loop in video.
but video not loading only first time, when start it's new load.

i want to play loop in offline, and load video only first time

how to do it's ?

Thank you

Comment: if you embed from youtube, i don't think you can control that how it's work.

Comment: @Feizhang210291 how to play viedo youtube in website without embed?, help please

Comment: Youtube should have cache strategies that make bandwidth usage efficient, so you don't need make this as consideration. maybe can you elaborate what kind of app that you want to make ?